# Manage Windows directory using batch(sorting and deleting)

Tags: windows, file-io, batch-file, command

I want to create a batch file that will sort the files(based on created date) in a directory and only keep x number of the most recent files.

The files also have a date/time in their names(ie. file201208140322) so if it's possible doing this by comparing current date/time to the substring I am open to this as well.

Can anybody help me with the command?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: you would probably be better using Python or something... command line in windows is pretty weak..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DIR /O-D /B /A-D` to get a list of files sorted in descending modification time, then feed the output of this command to `FOR /F` so that you get to process these files. Using `SET /A` you can increment a counter that keeps track of how many files we have seen so far, and after this counter reaches a certain threshold you can start deleting all subsequent entries.

Here's a batch file that does this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET PROCESSED_COUNT=0
SET SKIP_FIRST=5
SET START_PROCESSING=0
FOR /F %%f IN ('dir /o-d /b /a-d') DO CALL :process %%f
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :eof

:process
IF %PROCESSED_COUNT%==%SKIP_FIRST% SET START_PROCESSING=1
SET /A PROCESSED_COUNT=%PROCESSED_COUNT% + 1
IF %START_PROCESSING%==0 GOTO :eof
ECHO Delete file #%PROCESSED_COUNT%: %1
GOTO :eof
```

There are also other possible variations on this theme, so the above is not the only solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Where in the batch do I set the directory?

Comment: @user1171915: Either `CD` at the beginning or put the path in the `DIR` command. You can also set it as a variable if you prefer and use it with `"%VARIABLE_NAME%"`. The quotes are necessary if the path contains spaces.

Comment: Here is the ouput I am receiving from CMD:c:\Users\KJ>MaintainLogs
Delete file #3: ProcessPercentOwnership201208130951.txt
Delete file #4: ProcessPercentOwnership201208100951.txt
Delete file #5: REIDSExport.log

c:\Users\a101336>

Comment: But the files are not being deleted.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1171915: The code I posted has no `DEL` command, it simply prints stuff. You will have to add it yourself.

Comment: +1 for not deleting anything until you are sure it will delete what you expect it to